# Is there a known algorithm for scheduling tournament matchups?

Tags: algorithms

Just wondering if there is a tournament scheduling algorithm already out there that I could use or even adapt slightly.

Here are my requirements:

- A variable number of opponents belonging to a variable number of teams/clubs each must be paired with an opponent
- Two opponents cannot be from the same club
- If there are an odd number of players, 1 of them randomly is selected to get a bye

Any algorithms related to this sort of requirement set would be appreciated.

**EDIT:** I only need to run this a maximum of one time, creating matchups for the first 'round' of the tournament.

Comment: You might want to look into [maximum matching](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matching_%28graph_theory%29).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

As I can see you want to find [maximum matching](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matching_%28graph_theory%29) in graph. In fact nodes are players, they connected to each other if they aren't in same club, now you should find maximum number of edges which are doesn't have same vertex. See [Edmonds Maximum matching algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Edmonds%27s_matching_algorithm).

Answer (score 1):

From my brief time on Wikipedia twenty seconds ago it looks like you'll need to decide on an elimination strategy first.  See Wikipedia:

1. [Swiss-System](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Swiss_system_tournament)
2. [Single-elimination_tournament](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single-elimination_tournament)
3. [Double-elimination_tournament](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double-elimination_tournament)

The single-elimination article described seeding techniques (the algorithm you're looking for) pretty generically and it looked helpful, although not *quite* an algorithm.

Comment: I prefer Swiss, which gives middle rankings unlike double/single elimination, and finds the top N players in the same number of rounds as a N-elimination tournament.

Answer (score 1):

Making this up as I go, it seems like an initial matching algorithm is quite simple:

```
While two or more clubs have at least one member not paired  
    select the two clubs with the most unpaired members
    select a random unpaired member from each club
    pair those members
```

If one person is left, it will be a random person, with one exception.  If one club has more members than all of the opposing players put together, then the leftovers will always be from that club.  Realistically, that's a super-rare situation, and picking a buy from any other club would leave *even more* people leftover.